# Python - Pandas DF Sumproduct in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

What would be the fastest way to do the sum product of the below DF

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 6 |
| 5 | 5 |
| 7 | 5 |
| 8 | 2 |
| 6 | 11 |

I have a for loop :

```
for i in range(len(DF)) :
   Sumproduct = 0
```

What I aim to do in this for loop is for example if

```
i=1 then sumproduct = 2*6
i=2 then sumproduct = 2*6+5*5
i=3 then sumproduct = 2*6+5*5+7*5
```

Explanation in table :

| A | B | SumProduct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 6 |  |
| 5 | 5 | 2x6 |
| 7 | 5 | 2x6+5x5 |
| 8 | 2 | 2x6+5x5+7x5 |
| 6 | 11 | 2x6+5x5+7x5+8x2 |

ect...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That'll be cumsum on the product of the two columns then shift down:

```
df['SumProduct'] = df['A'].mul(df['B']).cumsum().shift()
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `prod()` and `cumsum()` with `shift()`

```
df.prod(axis=1).cumsum().shift()
```